SuiteScript 2.X Client Script Set Sublist Value not working
I'm attempting to uncheck a checkbox on the Sales Order transaction during line item entry if the location is a specific ID, I have tested with console.log() and confirmed I'm able to see the value, but for some reason when I attempt to set the value it won't work.
I've tried a number of recommended answers but nothing has worked so far, here is my script:


/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/action', 'N/currentRecord', 'N/record', 'N/transaction'],
/**
 * @param{action} action
 * @param{currentRecord} currentRecord
 * @param{record} record
 * @param{transaction} transaction
 */
function(action, currentRecord, record, transaction) {
    
    /**
     * Function to be executed after sublist is inserted, removed, or edited.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function sublistChanged(scriptContext) {
        var recLoc = scriptContext.currentRecord.getValue('location');

        if(recLoc == 79) {
            var line = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');

            nlapiSetLineItemValue('item','createwo',line,'F');
        };
    }

    return {
        sublistChanged: sublistChanged
    };
    
});



I appreciate any insight!
Update
I've adjusted my script using Karl-Henry Martinsson's suggestions but I'm still unable to uncheck the checkbox, here is my new code:


/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/action', 'N/currentRecord', 'N/record', 'N/transaction'],
/**
 * @param{action} action
 * @param{currentRecord} currentRecord
 * @param{record} record
 * @param{transaction} transaction
 */
function(action, currentRecord, record, transaction) {
    
    /**
     * Function to be executed after sublist is inserted, removed, or edited.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function sublistChanged(scriptContext) {
        var currRec = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        var sublistId = scriptContext.sublistId;
        var recLoc = currRec.getValue({
            fieldId: 'location'
        });
        
        if(recLoc === '79') {
            if(sublistId === 'item') {
                console.log('success');

                currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: sublistId,
                    fieldId: 'createwo',
                    value: false,
                    ignoreFieldChange: true
                });
            };
        };
    }

    return {
        sublistChanged: sublistChanged
    };
    
});




Two things I noticed about your script:

As already noted by Karl, you are using SuiteScript 1.0 functions within a SuiteScript 2.x script.  In a client script, the functions will be available, but they aren't guaranteed to be compatible.
The value of your variable line is being set to the line count of the sublist you're targeting.  This means that in a 1-indexed API like SS1.0 you would always be targeting the last line in the sublist, or with a 0-indexed API like SS2.0 you would be targeting one line beyond the end (IE: a non-existent line).  Not sure what happens with a SS1.0 function inside a SS2.0 script.

I'm also not sure that sublistChanged() is the best event to trigger this on.  From what I've seen, this does not work as you'd expect for your scenario, because it will be triggered after the line is committed, so by the time the function runs, the "current line" will have changed.
Another consideration is at what point you want to make the decision to unset the createwo field, and whether NetSuite field sourcing has any effect.  The createwo field is sourced when the item is added, based on the setting of the "Special Work Order Item" setting on the item record.  If you set the value before the sourcing occurs, is will be overwritten.
To address these issues, you can use the postSourcing() entry point to check and update the field immediately after the item is entered:
function postSourcing(context) {
    if (context.sublistId == 'item' && context.fieldId == 'item') {
        var recLoc = context.currentRecord({
            fieldId: 'location'
        });
        if (recLoc == 79) {
            context.currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                fieldId: 'createwo',
                sublistId: 'item',
                value: false
            });
        }
    }
}

You could alternatively use validateLine to check and update the value immediately before the line is committed - when you click Add on each line instead of immediately after you set the Item.

Thank you for the explanation! Your solution worked, I tried validateLine before but it wouldn't allow me to add lines to my SO after for some reason? I used postSourcing and that did the trick, thanks again!

It's likely that validateLine didn't work for you because you didn't return true at the end.  The validate entry points are there to allow checking (validating) according to custom logic and then "approving" or "rejecting" the change.  If the entry point function is present, you need to return true to "approve" the change and proceed with the action.  Anyway, glad it helped!

Oh, that's good to know! Thank you for that!

First of all, you are using SuiteScript 1.0 (nlapiGetLineItemCount and nlapiSetLineItemValue) in a script you designated as SuiteScript 2.0.
I am surprised that you don't get an error there.
My suggestion is that you use SuiteScript 2.0 for the whole script.
You should also use scriptContext.sublistId to make sure you have the correct id, instead of hard-coding 'item'.
The code to use is slightly different, depending on if you use dynamic or standard mode. Since your script is a client script, I think you need to use dynamic mode.
The question is: is the requirement that the checkbox is unchecked directly when the line is entered, or can it be done when the record is saved? My preference would be to do this in a beforeSuybmiut user event script.
Your code could look something like this:
var currRec = scriptContext.currentRecord;
var sublistId = scriptContext.sublistId;
currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: sublistId,
    fieldId: 'createwo',
    value: false,
    ignoreFieldChange: true
});


Hello, thank you for your response! That's my bad on using Suitescript 1.0 functions, I wasn't aware. Using your provided code doesn't uncheck the createwo checkbox, is this supposed to be a user event script? I'm hoping to change this upon line add via client script if possible.
